# Make 3 columns with last class in loop

Tags: php, html, css, for-loop, blueprint-css

I want to make a 3 columns and add `last` class to third column.  I tried this code:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i = $i + 4) { //can't touch this line ?>
<?php for ($j = $i; $j < ($i + 4); $j++) { //can't touch this line ?>

<?php $counter=0; ?>
            <div class="span-5<?php if ($counter % 3 == 0) { echo " last"; } ?>">
Info    
            </div>              


<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

but it doesn't help. (it assigns `last` class to second column)

Comment: `can't touch this line` is a handy comment! :P

Comment: The code as is will assign last to every column, because your counter is not incremented, so it will always be 0.

Comment: Err.. where is counter being incremented? Bit hard to figure out why `last` is ever applied at present!

Answer (score 3):

Add a `$counter++` at the right time and it will work.

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i = $i + 4) { //can't touch this line ?>
<?php for ($j = $i; $j < ($i + 4); $j++) { //can't touch this line ?>

<?php $counter=0; ?>
            <div class="span-5<?php $counter++; if ($counter % 3 == 0) { echo " last"; } ?>">
Info    
            </div>              


<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.it may help you.

```
 <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i = $i + 4) { //can't touch this line ?>
    <?php for ($j = $i; $j < ($i + 4); $j++) { //can't touch this line ?>

    <?php if($j == 3){
         $class = 'class="last"';
     }else{
         $class = '';
     } ?>
                <div <?php $class; ?>>
    Info    
                </div>    




<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: hi, here you can change your class directly if you want to change and also apply other class for all columns other than 3. and also your code is customized with this code.        Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Or just set your `$counter` to `$j+1`.